# How To Rotate Objects Using C# Script In Unity2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm Trying To Rotate My Coin Object to 0z if Y is above 0.17f and if its not will rotate back to 90z , the first if statement works fine but the other one keeps rotating my coin and i don't know why...? I'm Completely New To Unity and C# Lang !

Anyway Here's my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject coin;
 
    bool isRotated = false;
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (coin.transform.position.y > 0.17f && coin.transform.rotation.z >= 0f && !isRotated)
        {
           
            coin.transform.Rotate(coin.transform.rotation.x,coin.transform.rotation.y,-1f );
 
            if (coin.transform.rotation.z <= 0f)
            {
                isRotated = true;
            }
 
        }else if (coin.transform.position.y < 0.17f && coin.transform.rotation.z <= 90f && isRotated)
        {
           
            coin.transform.Rotate(coin.transform.rotation.x,coin.transform.rotation.y,1f);
           
            if (coin.transform.rotation.z >= 90f)
            {
                isRotated = false;
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)!

As the name suggests a `Quaternion` (also see Wikipedia -> Quaternion has not three but **four** components `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`. All these move within the range `-1` to `+1`. Unless you really know exactly what you are doing you **never** touch these components directly.

---

If I understand you correctly you rather want to do something like e.g.

```
public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform coin;
    public float anglePerSecond = 90;
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var targetRotation = coin.position.y > 0.17f ? Quaternion.identity : Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);

        coin.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(coin.rotation, targetRotation, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! , I think now i know what to do (: ❤️